# Rails: Create Method - How to add HABTM attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
if current_user.blank?
      @order.create_user(email: @order.email, name: @order.name, ???????? )
end
```

I'm trying to add @order.addresses.first to the new user. User and Address are HABTM.

What should I add on @order.create_user( ????? )? Maybe @order.create_user( addresses.first: @order.addresses.first ) ?

OK,I have the nested_attributes already.

What I'm doing now is less elegant.

```
if current_user.blank?
    @order.create_user(email: @order.email, name: @order.name)
    @order.user.addresses << @order.addresses.first.address
    @order.save
end
```

Any idea to make it better?

Comment: you're looking for `nested_attributes`

Comment: I've already have the nested_attributes, I just wanted to include an address to the new user from order by using the create method.

User and Address models are HABTM and Address and Order are also in HABTM.

I'm trying to figure out how to use the create method in a better way.

Comment: Ok, do: create_user(addresses_attributes: [...])

Comment: Merci beaucoup! That's what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: Derien :) Just submitted as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer lies in my comments: use nested attributes.